# Blazor server side deployment http 500 error

Tags: c#, mysql, http, deployment, blazor

i have a problem when i deploy my blazor app (self-contained or framework-dependent) to a private server.
App works properly on visual studio debug mode, i can process crud operations even on remote server.
However when i deploy the app, i get http 500 error and i cant find any additional information. None of the pages are opening.

I checked the _Host.cshtml and Startup.cs files. The app doesn't have complex pages or packages for now, only use asp net core identity with ef core.

Where should i look into first, what could you suggest?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN50q.png

Comment: The first step is to deploy a default project to the same server / service, and see if THAT works.   I had this problem when I upgraded from .net Core 3.1 to .net 5: no matter how much I tried to fix the project, I could only get it to run in self-contained mode.  You may find that copying all your components and files to a newly-created project will be less painful than trying to "fix" an upgraded project.

Comment: Nope, it's all 5.0. I read about other issues, my solutution's Host.cshtml file have `<link href="{myApplication}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` . Once i opened this solution to vs 2022 preview and then i re-created the solution on vs 2019 again, both didn't work. And yes, the default app works on server.

Comment: Is it IIS?  You have correct type of app pool on server?  I think if you use self-contained publish, then any error must be server config problem.

Comment: I have the same problem deploying a Blazor server side application .Net Core 6 to IIS. Even when deploying the raw default template with no modifications

Answer (score 1):

Finally i find the solution.

When i deploy the app on azure, it says there is a error about mysqlconnector, and i delete `ServerVersion.AutoDetect` (Pomelo package), set the version by hand in Startup.cs and it works. But i don't know why it works.